# You have untill Saturday to figure this out!

Tags: riddle

I live if you drop me off a building but I die if you put me in water. What am I?

Comment: As you can see, there are so many valid possibilities for your puzzle which indicates it is too broad. Hence 4 close votes. Please add some clear restriction to narrow it. My 2 cents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be

> paper? Or a calender?
>
>  It'll float down from the top of a building, but will be destroyed in water.

I thought of this because of @oleslaw's comment about the title being a hint

Answer (score 4):

I think it is

> The coworker sitting next to me

I live if you drop me off a building

> He never took a day off for being sick.

but I die if you put me in water.

> Maybe that is why he smells like that.

You have untill Saturday to figure this out!

> He does not work on weekends.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it is

> Cotton candy. Low terminal velocity, but is dissolved if you put it in water.

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 Ideas for an answer, my hope maybe one of them will be true:

1:

> **A bird** (meaning a regular bird, not a Seabird)-If you drop her out of a building she'll just fly, but if you put her in the water she'll probably die.

2:

> **A house cat**-He will survive the fall thanks to the cat righting reflex ,But he will not survive swimming for a long time because entering the water leads him to rapid exhaustion (especially if he is a spoiled house cat).

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer maybe

> ant?
>  Because the ants are so small the gravity affecting them is really tiny. There have been calculations that an ant can fall off the Empire State Building, and still remain unharmed. And naturally if you leave it in the water the ant would drown.

Comment: rot13(Jryy gur nppryrengvba qhr gb tenivgl vf gur fnzr nf nalguvat ryfr fb gur znff bs gur nag znxrf ab qvssrerapr va guvf ertneq. Vg vf npghnyyl nve erfvfgnapr gung unf na rssrpg ba vgf grezvany irybpvgl)

Comment: @Adam rot(Bs pbhefr gung gur znff cynlf n ovt cneg va guvf znggre. Vs n crefba jbhyq whzc bss n ohvyqvat nve erfvfgnapr jbhyq abg uryc gurz zhpu. Orpnhfr n crefbaf jrvtug (z*t) vf jnl uvture guna nve erfvfgnapr.)

Comment: rot13(V'z qvfchgvat "fb fznyy gur tenivgl nssrpgvat gurz vf ernyyl gval". Vs V jrer gb fgevc gur nag qbja gb (yrgf fnl) ryrpgebaf, gur rssrpg gur tenivgl jbhyq unir ba rnpu ryrpgeba vf gur fnzr nf vs vg jrer fgvyy na nag. Vs gurer jnf ab nve, gur nag jbhyq rnfvyl qvr yvxr nalbar ryfr. Nyfb, gur znff bs gur guvat snyyvat gbjneqf gur Rnegu qbrf nssrpg vgf grezvany irybpvgl ubjrire n ernyyl sng crefba pbhyq rnfvyl fheivir guvf snyy whfg yvxr gur nag vs gurl unq n ynetr fhesnpr nern. Vg vfa'g arprffnevyl gehr gb fnl gung jrvtug vf gur fbyr pnhfr bs qrngu sebz snyyvat) So basically ima grammar boi!

Comment: rot(Bu, lrnu, V nterr, "gur tenivgl nssrpgvat gurz vf ernyyl gval" jnfa'g ernyyl gur orfg pubvpr bs jbeqf. kQ Naq lrnu, V nterr gur jrvtug vf abg gur bayl guvat nssrpgvat, V whfg qvqa'g svaq vg arprffnel gb qrgnvy fb zhpu nobhg vg urer... :))

Answer (score 1):

My answer is

> Origami: a [paper bird](https://youtu.be/nYs_NMbDKk0?t=325).
>
>   I thought of this because of the [answer from @tryin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/86529/51581).

Answer (score 1):

> Skylines come alive as they are drop from buildings, they die as they enter the water. Same as base jumpers.

Answer (score 0):

> Fire
>  1. Fresh air from falling makes it even bigger
>  2. Fire dies in water obviously

Comment: However I believe the title should be a hint to this, in which case this is not a correct answer

Comment: Unless they actually meant that we have until Saturday to solve it!

Answer (score 0):

My answer is

> Seeds or plants buds
>
>  It will fly in the air, if it gets proper soil and nutrition, it will become a tree(live), otherwise, if we put it in water, it only gets water and died.

Thanks